# Decompile help file and extract context mappings?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, chm

I have an old help file project, but the original project was lost in a hard drive crash. The original was created using HelpScribble, but now I've decompiled it into WinCHM. I have recreated the help file after decompiling the original compiled CHM file. However, to my knowledge, there is no way to identify the mappings to direct an application to certain Context ID's.

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to read the compiled CHM file and extract the Context ID of each topic in the help file? I would hate to have to iterate through individual numbers from 0 to 5,000 from what I've seen in the original software source. This is a large system, and has a corresponding large help file for every possible scenario in the software.

Comment: ?? Googling "extract context ids from chm" has as its first hit ChmDecompiler which seesm to be doing what you want http://download.cnet.com/ChmDecompiler/3000-10247_4-10387255.html. Or am I missing something?

Comment: 1) Some decompilers refuse to decompile if "extended decompilation" (or something similar) wasn't on in the .hhp. 2) some only decompile the overall archive structure, but don't reverse the internal files back to original input. That said, I don't know that tool, but it is trialware so might have limitations on CHM size and complexity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `chmls` tool from the [FreePascal](http://www.freepascal.org/) project. Invoke it like this:

```
chmls extractalias MyHelpFile.chm
```

The output are files named `MyHelpFile.ali` and `MyHelpFile.h` containing the IDs and targets of your aliases.